# get(0,'screensize') giving result [0 0 1 1] instead of actual pixels

Tags: matlab, properties, matlab-figure

During MATLAB-sessions,`get(0,'screensize')` first gives the correct resolution. Later on, the answer will become `[0 0 1 1]` though. This behaviour will only stop when I restart matlab, it is then the correct value again.

This error always happens when I run a specific part of our programme. It appears to happen after this specific line of code:

```
 set(0,'PointerLocation',[.4*GUI.scrsz(3),.5*GUI.scrsz(4)],'units','normalized');
```

Even though I managed to isolate the error I can´t to figure out the reason for this behaviour.  I am using MATLAB R2010b on Windows 7 64bit.

Please note that I´m not an advanced user of MATLAB, so please forgive me if i overlooked something obvious.Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you set `'units'` to `'normalized'`. And your screen starts naturally in a corner -> `[0 0 ...` and fills the whole screen -> `... 1 1]` (The first pair defines the position and the second pair height and width)
So the values are correct, just not showing the pixels anymore.

Just set it back to `set(0,'units','pixels')` after you finished the task before, which needed the normalized units. Or store your screensize at the beginning of your script in a variable to use it later on.

With `get(0,...)` you are getting default properties and with `set(0,...)` you change them, thats why it's normal again after restart, because Matlab is setting all values to default with every start, which is in your case `'units','pixels'`.

Comment: Uh, thats quite obvious, how embarassing... Thanks a lot for the quick and more than complete answer!

Comment: I corrected it in the following way:

`GUI.scrsz = get(0, 'ScreenSize');
set(0,'PointerLocation',[.4*GUI.scrsz(3),.5*GUI.scrsz(4)]);`

This way I don´t have to mess around with different units. Thanks again!